# Regx :Finding first non-repeated consecutive charecter

Tags: python-3.x

Please check the requirement this is not repeated question.
Need to find out first non repeated consecutive occurence of charecter using Regx

```
Str1="aabbcdde"
output:- c 

str2="abbccddee"
Output:- a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group characters together, then count the length of those groups, stopping when you find one of length 1.

```
from itertools import groupby

def non_repeating(s):
    for k, g in groupby(s):
        if sum(1 for _ in g) == 1: # This can probably be improved
            return k
    return None # Or whatever failure value is appropriate
```

Edit:

Here's a function that takes some iterator and tests whether it is one element long or not, consuming some portion of it

```
from itertools import groupby

def is_one(g):
    try:
        next(g) # Has a first element, should succeed
    except StopIteration:
        return False # Empty iterator
    try:
        next(g) # Has a second element should fail
    except StopIteration:
        return True # There was only one element
    return False # There was more than one element

def non_repeating(s):
    for k, g in groupby(s):
        if is_one(g):
            return k
    return None # Or whatever failure value is appropriate
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick!! I understand g will have list of all same consecutive characters but did not understand  sum(1 for _ in g) == 1,can you please explain ?

Comment: `g` is an iterable that will be consumed as we iterate through it.  This is basically the poor mans `len(g)`, because `itertools._grouper` objects don't support `len`.  It's imperfect because we keep counting even if we know the answer will be greater than one, but the improved version would be pretty hard to read, and this version isn't too inefficent

Comment: If we want an early stop approach which is readable, maybe use islice, whether with a list as in `next(k for k,g in groupby(s) if len(list(islice(g, 2))) == 1)` or with the sum-of-1s.  (Of course in the real world we just spent longer thinking about this than we're ever likely to save. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex can be used to remove the repeated letters.

```
    preg_replace("/(?<first>[a-z]+)(\k<first>)/", "", $input_lines);
```

Then you can just pull out the first letter (since your first example has two non-repeating letters). Tested on [enter link description here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Comment: Was this solution in python? I was talking about the solution using re module of python.

Comment: Oops sorry, you said Python, I heard PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in python, but I know this regex can capture any character matches which is `repeated`. You can just adjust `.` into `\w` if you want to capture only `word`

[REGEX](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cw)%5C1%2B&test_string=aafffsdd%0Aaaa%0Akkfjjv%0Aa%0Alll%0Afpeii%0Ap%0Akk%0Annndppe%0Akkk%0Appfp%5Bw%0Aj%0Ann%0Aldppel%0Aj%0Ak%0Akk%0Ajg--%0A22200ll%0A%3D%0Af%0A%2C%2C%0A..lslljj&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0):

```
(\w)\1+
this regex means: match all characters repeated
```

You could just replace all matches into empty string, then the first character of string is the first `non-repeated` word

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It doesn't work - it will match every unique character, including only the last repetition of repeated ones, cause they aren't followed by itself.

Comment: I was referring to the previous version you posted tbh ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some `re` solution - instead of finding unrepeated characters it just removes the ones, which repeat.

```py
import re

str1="aabbcdde"

str2="abbccddee"
print(str1)
for el in re.sub(r"(.)\1+", "", str1):
    print(el)

print(str2)
for el in re.sub(r"(.)\1+", "", str2):
    print(el)
```

Outputs:

```py
aabbcdde
c
e
abbccddee
a
```